# I need to integrate POS device to my c# .Net WPF application to verify payment which is better way?

Tags: square, square-checkout

I have created a WPF application and integrate checkout-api successfully for payment via payment-url. Now I want to integrate POS device so can access card payment also at same application. Please guide, suggest a proper way to integrate it

I am trying with [this](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/terminal-api/pos-integration)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely build with the Terminal API to process in person payments. Please note that your application will need to be running on another device since 3rd party apps can't be added to Square Terminal. All payments will push via API to the Terminal device where they'll be completed.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find such things are not allowed on SO. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Do not answer such questions. Vote to close them instead. [answer]